# jxbrowser - Will it detect the browser or jre version and work

Tags: jxbrowser

I wanted to use jxBrowser in our Swing based application (Thick Client), When the client access out application thru JNLP file, The program should detect the client installed browser and detect jre version 32 bit/bit JVM and work based on the Environment ?

Thanks,
Subu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JxBrowser doesn't detect the installed web browser because it deploys all required Chromium files inside its Jar files. The installed JRE is detected by OS and Java Web Start, so JxBrowser doesn't need to detect JRE.